# Why doesn't mbtowc count character set as expected?

Tags: c, linux

I want count the characters (in various charsets) in a file and I'm using the function 'mbtowc' to detect the characters. I cannot figure out why the chars and results values are different. Here is my example:

```
char buf[BUFFER_SIZE + MB_LEN_MAX];

int fd = open ("chinese_test", O_RDONLY);

unsigned int bytes, chars;

int bytes_read;

bytes = chars = 0;

while((bytes_read = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
    wchar_t wc_buf[BUFFER_SIZE], *wcp;
    char *p;
    int n = 0;

    bytes += bytes_read;

    p = buf;
    wcp = wc_buf;

    while((n = mbtowc(wcp, p, MB_LEN_MAX)) > 0) {
        p += n;
        wcp++;

        chars++;
    }

}

printf("chars: %d\tbytes: %d\n", chars, bytes);
```

I test the function with a text with some GB2312 characters, but *chars* and *bytes* are too different values.

My test returns -> chars: 4638 | bytes: 17473
but 'wc' linux command returns: chars: 16770 | bytes: 17473

Why this difference? What did I do wrong?

---

Now I've this code but there are still soe difference in the result.

```
char buf[BUFFER_SIZE * MB_LEN_MAX];

int fd = open ("test_chinese", O_RDONLY), filled = 0;

unsigned int bytes, chars;

int bytes_read;

bytes = chars = 0;

while((bytes_read = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
    wchar_t wc_buf[BUFFER_SIZE], *wcp;
    char *p;
    int n = 0;

    bytes += bytes_read;

    p = buf;
    wcp = wc_buf;



    while(bytes_read > 0) {
        n = mbtowc(NULL, p, MB_LEN_MAX);

        if (n <= 0) {
            p++;
            bytes_read--;
            continue;
        }
        p += n;

        bytes_read -= n;

        chars++;
    }

}

printf("\n\nchars: %d\tbytes: %d\n", chars, bytes);
```

Comment: Depending on you `BUFFER_SIZE` and the size of the file you read, you might get incomplete multibyte sequences. Add a check after the `while`  loop to see if `n` is negative to be certain.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I know this problem. Is it possible that with a file of 17473 Byte and with the BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 are there so many errors?

Comment: Probably not, but you should check for this anyway. The most likely culprit is the one pointed out in the answer by Swiss.

Comment: On a closer look, your code looks fine except for the issue brought up by Joachim. I think I might know what the issue is though. Could you provide an excerpt from `chinese_test`?

Comment: @Swiss this is the file: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bx4Iapl7KEeXYjYzN2EzMDQtNDM5Yy00YzAwLWJkMDMtMTZjYmVhYWJiYmU0

Comment: Noticed a possible bug: You probably meant to use `char buf[BUFFER_SIZE * MB_LEN_MAX];` on the first line.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is a combination of your `BUFFER_SIZE`, the file size of `chinese_test` and the byte alignment of `wchar_t`. As proof, try drastically increasing `BUFFER_SIZE`- you should start getting the answer you want.

What is happening is that your program works for the first block of text that it receives. But think about what happens in your code if a character is split between the first and second blocks as follows:

```
  | First Block                 | Second Block      |
  | [wchar_t] [wchar_t] ... [wchar_t] [wchar_t] ... |
  | [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] ... [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] ... |
```

Your code will begin the second block on the 3rd byte in the first character, and that will not be recognized as a valid character. Since `mbtowc` will return `-1` when it does not find a valid character, your loop will immediately end and will count zero characters for that entire block. The same will apply for the following blocks.

EDIT:
Another issue I noticed is that you need to set the locale in order for `mbtowc` to work correctly. Taking all of these issues into account, I wrote the following which returns the same character count as `wc` for me:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
const char *DEFAULT_F_IN = "chinese_test";

struct counts {
    int bytes;
    int chars;
};

int count_block(struct counts *c, char *buf, int buf_size)
{
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < buf_size) {
        int n = mbtowc(NULL, buf + offset, MB_CUR_MAX);
        if (n <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        offset += n;
        c->bytes += n;
        c->chars++;
    }

    return buf_size - offset;
}

void get_counts(struct counts *c, FILE *fd)
{
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    c->bytes = 0;
    c->chars = 0;

    int bytes_read;
    while((bytes_read = fread(buf, sizeof(*buf), BUFFER_SIZE, fd)) > 0) {
        int remaining = count_block(c, buf, bytes_read);
        if (remaining == 0) {
            continue;
        } else if (remaining < MB_CUR_MAX) {
            fseek(fd, -remaining, SEEK_CUR);
        } else {
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fd;
    if (argc > 1) {
        fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    } else {
        fd = fopen(DEFAULT_F_IN, "rb");
    }

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    struct counts c;
    get_counts(&c, fd);
    printf("chars: %d\tbytes: %d\n", c.chars, c.bytes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mbtowc()` returns -1 if there is an incomplete multibyte character.

Comment: @caf Whoops. Thanks for the catch. I have corrected it now though.

Comment: @Swiss With this while I've _chars:16634_; but your code raise a segmentation fault

`while(bytes_read > 0) {
   n = mbtowc(NULL, p, MB_LEN_MAX);

   if (n <= 0) {
    p++;
    bytes_read--;
    continue;
   }
   p += n;
   
   bytes_read -= n;
   
   chars++;
  }`

Comment: I have updated the code to fix the segfault. By using an offset relative to buf rather than a separate pointer, you can track when you are past the end of the buffer.

Comment: @Storted: The code sample I provide now completely works for me. Working with Unicode in C is a PITA.